# mySql regular expression in WHERE statement

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wildcard

I have a database where I store a code which is an implode("|", $array) of various codes.  So the results will be something like:

- 100|5100|510
- 100|5200|510
- 410|5200|520
- 100|790|5100|320

I want to write a regular expression to search mySQL for matches from PHP ...  I might have something like 100|*|510 to show me both 100|5100|510 and 100|5200|510.   This RegEx works in PHP:

/100\|(?:.*)\|510/

But it does not work in mySQL.  I found answers that ?: does not work, so if I remove that and use

/100\|.*\|510/

i.e. Query is: 
SELECT * FROM tra_amounts WHERE coa_codes REGEXP "/100\|.*\|510/"

It shows all results from the table.

How do I write a RegEx to match some parts of the code, while leaving other parts of the code as a wildcard?

Thanks!

Comment: You could do `100\|[0-9]+\|510`, that would allow any number in the middle. In your examples should `100|790|5100|320` not be matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of MySQL's `LIKE` operator?  Something like this might be what you have in mind:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE someCol LIKE '100|%|510;
```

Assuming that `someCol` had `100|5100|510` and `100|5200|510` as data, this query would return both of these records.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RLIKE` instead of `LIKE` or `=`.